# Kinect Stream Saving

Tags: c#, c++, video-streaming, kinect

So I am using Microsoft Kinect Studio to playback some collected data. I am only dealing with color and depth images.

So I have a stream saver program that allows me to save the streams but if my video is about 30 seconds long, I am only able to save the first 10 seconds properly but the rest my stream saver program starts to lag and loose data

I am not too proficient in C++ or C# is there is program out there that can allow me to save both streams properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the first 10 seconds work fine, suggests to me that you're running out of cache space on your hard disk. If you're saving the video stream uncompressed, in full HD, you're saving about 180MB/sec. You might have some luck downscaling the video (at 960x540 you're just saving about 45MB/sec) or compressing it, but then you might run into CPU issues.

Comment: I have been trying to downscaling the video aswell but I am not sure how to go about doing that. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: @AliP If you're up for some programming, I can suggest some ways. You can make it very simple or very hard, depending on the quality you're after. If you don't care about quality, you could just grab every second pixel (something like `for(int i = 0; i < image.width; i += 2`). If you want better quality you're looking at algorithms like bicubic interpolation.

Comment: actually the main problem I found out is that Kinect Studio is actually using pretty much all my RAM and when I run at the same time as my own developped program, I encounter those lags... Any suggestions on that part?

Comment: @AliP There's not much you can do about KS using a lot of RAM. But you could check if your own application could use less RAM. Try to reuse memory, instead of allocating new memory. But at some point you obviously use the minimum RAM possible.